# How can I get one alert via if operator only ? (just started JavaScript learning)

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, alerts

Here the part of code from the book "Beginning JS 4th edition". When I load it in a browser that will show me 2 times alerts, because I entered 2 NaNs in array.
I'd like displaying alert just one time always, how can I get that knowing only if operator?

```
if (isNaN(degFahren[loopCounter]))

{ 
alert ("You have text parameters that will be skipped");
continue;
}
```

I understand that loop have to run only one time inside @if block, but can't realize that(((

Thank you!!!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to accomplish that with your `continue`. Can you show more of your code, including your loop and how the loop is being called?

Comment: Please click the `<>` button in the editor and create a [mcve] with input and expected output

Comment: There is no effect of continue statement in your code. As it is at bottom of the loop it is used, I guess if you are trying to come out of the inner loop then use return instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the appropriate array method, `includes`, to see if an array includes a particular element.

```js
const arr = [1, NaN, NaN, 4];
if(arr.includes(NaN)) {
  alert('You have text parameters that will be skipped.');
}
```

You don't need double nested `for` loops.

If you need to check *how many times* a particular element is in an array, you can use `.filter` to create a new array with only the matching elements and check the new array's `length`:

```js
const arr = [1, NaN, NaN, 4];
const NaNs = arr.filter(item => isNaN(item));
if(NaNs.length > 0) {
  alert('You have text parameters that will be skipped: ' + NaNs.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most generic approach would be to introduce a variable:

```
var numberOfWarnings = 0;
```

Increment and test its value whenever there's reason to show an alert:

```
if (numberOfWarnings++ == 0) alert("You'll see me only if I was first.");
```

Comment: Thanky, that's good decision!  I added  this and it shows only one times as I wanted but document.writes shows the text string.. that I would'n want it. 

Value 0 was 212 degrees Fahrenheit which is 100 degrees centigrade
....
Value 6 was naxxx degrees Fahrenheit which is NaN degrees centigrade

Comment: @RomanTselenko You need help calling `document.write` if input is not NaN? Try `else`.